# send email from localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, localhost

I'm try learn about email in rails. I'm developing something on localhost. Is it possible to send an email from localhost to say a normal mail account like gmail? Do I have a install a mail server? I've just got a standard rails installation at the moment for development.

Comment: "send email from localhost" - not looks like ruby specified question

Answer (score 31):

Update for rails 4.0
Now you need these code to make it work:

```
# I recommend using this line to show error
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :domain         => 'mail.google.com',
  :port           => 587,
  :user_name      => 'foo@gmail.com',
  :password       => '******',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to restart your rails server

Comment: If you follow these instructions, Gmail blocks the delivery and sends this email to the user_name you used: "Google will continue to block sign-in attempts from the app you're using because it has known security problems or is out of date. You can continue to use this app by allowing access to less secure apps, but this may leave your account vulnerable."

Comment: `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` no longer works in the latest Rails versions. You have to use `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` instead now.

Answer (score 16):

You can set up ActionMailer to use Gmail's SMTP server using something like this in **config/environment.rb**:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.server_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :domain         => '<your domain>',
    :port           => 587,
    :user_name      => '<your gmail>',
    :password       => '<your password>',
    :authentication => :plain
}
```

**Edit**: If you experience any difficulties, set your config to display errors:

```
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: thanks, so if I'm trying to send an email from localhost (not make the sender a regular email account like gmail) to a regular mailbox like gmail what do I put in the :domain, :user_name, :password and : authentication fields?

Comment: This in only the setup for which mail server to use. The from address, to address, subject and so on are changed elsewhere. See the examples in the documentation for ActionMailer (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) on how to do this.

Comment: for gmail :enable_starttls_auto: true sometimes may be nesessary

Comment: `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` no longer works in the latest Rails versions. You have to use `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` instead now.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html). In `RAILS_ROOT/config/environment/` , there is a file for different environments (development, test, production) the configurable settings go in these files

You specify the delivery_method like this,

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

or if you want

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

A detailed example of the settings has been posted by Mikael S

HTH

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your situation correctly, you want to send an email from your local computer using a custom email address such as john@mycompany.com. If you already registered the domain name for your email account ( mycompany.com ) is very likely that the company that is hosting your website, also has a POP/SMTP server. If so, you can use Mikael S's sample and change the address parameter to your Hosting company's smtp address and use your hosting company's username/password.

If you have not register your custom domain or don't have a hosting provider, you can install a free email server in your local computer. If you use WindowsXP, you can add the IIS email server by going to add/remove programs->windows features. If you are using Linux, you can use any of the email servers available in the repositories. Once you install your local email server you will use Mikael S's sample code and use 127.0.0.1 or localhost in the address field. If you are using WindowsXP's email server, I think you don't have to enter username/password.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can send it from localhost, you can even set the sender as a 'real' mailbox e.g. you@gmail.com.

However, some (or say most) servers will not accept this mail as part of their [spam blocking strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#PTR.2FReverse_DNS_checks) (inability to verify the sender identity).
However, In the past, I have had something similar with python which worked on gmail.

so good luck ;-)