# Sending smtp in rails using gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I am trying to send an activation email in development mode, i am using  application.yml to enter my smtp credentials not sure what I am missing but for some reason i'm not able to send the activation email. here is the

application.yml

```
SMTP_PORT: 587
  SMTP_DOMAIN: localhost:3000
  SMTP_ADDRESS: smtp.gmail.com
  SMTP_USERNAME: myemail@gmail.com
  SMTP_PASSWORD: myemailpassword
  SMTP_AUTHENTICATION: 'plain'
  enable_starttls_auto: true
```

development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file
  config.action_mailer.file_settings = { location: 'tmp/mails' }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV["URL_HOST"] }
```

token_mailer.rb

```
  def activation(email, token)
    @token_url = edit_activation_url token
    mail to: email
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried everything from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789032/send-email-from-localhost

Comment: This might be relevant - skip to the correct answer http://serverfault.com/questions/589458/cannot-get-exim4-gmail-working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this in development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :user_name => "your mail",
     :password => "your password",
     :authentication => :plain,
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: thank you mate even i faced the same situation and it worked out for me.

Comment: Now in 2017 You  must activate the option about insecurity apps

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Turn on this option and it's all

Comment: What `:plain` means ?

Answer (score 3):

**setup mailer to send emails**

in app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Mailer
  default from: "no-reply@myapp.com"

def welcome(user_email)
   @user=User.find_by_email user_email
   Rails.logger.info "==========sending welcome email to ==> #{@user.email}"
   mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Hi #{@user.username},Welcome to #{configatron.app_name}")
end
 end
```

**setup view file to send as email**

```
app/views/user_emailer/welcome.html.erb

<p>Hi <%= @user.username %>,Welcome to myapp.com</p>
```

**setup email configurations**

in config/initializers/email_setup.rb

```
if Rails.env != 'test'
  email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/email.yml"))
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = email_settings[Rails.env] unless email_settings[Rails.env].nil?
end
```

**setup keys/passwords,using gmail..for development but use mailchimp/mandrill for pro**

```
in config/email.yml

    development:
      :address: smtp.gmail.com
      :port: 587
      :authentication: plain
      :user_name: milind@gmail.com
      :password: password
      :enable_starttls_auto: true
    production:
      :address: smtp.gmail.com
      :port: 587
      :authentication: plain
      :user_name: milind@gmail.com
      :password: password
      :enable_starttls_auto: true
```

**user mailer to send email**

```
UserMailer.welcome(current_user).deliver
```

HOPE IT HELPS.... :)

Answer (score 1):

try this in your development.rb file

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :authentication => :plain,
      :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
      :user_name => 'your_gmail_email',
      :password => 'your_password'
  }
```