# Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 1025 - Devise Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionmailer, development-environment

I am trying to send an email after signup for rails devise. Unfortunately I am getting the error in the title.

Here is my development environment:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Am I not supposed to be going through port 1025? I'm very new to rails mailers, so any insight into this would be appreciated!

Comment: im guessing this is in production?

Comment: Do you actually have an smtp service listening on port 1025 on localhost?  Rails isn't going to start one for you.

Comment: @Marv-C this is on my local computer

Comment: @KarenB I'm ashamed to say I don't know. How would I check this, or set it up?

Comment: I have this set up inside my `development.rb` with devise and it works well  `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: localhost:3000 }`

Comment: @Marv-C When I do this, the server shows the email being sent, but I do not receive it in my email.

Comment: @gwalshington i see. i actually test my mailer through heroku sendgrid. but i found this link, it might help you set up in localhost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789032/send-email-from-localhost

Comment: @Marv-C Thanks. I'll look into SendGrid as well!

Comment: @Marv-C I just sent up SendGrid, and it works fine! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @gwalshington nice. Keep it rails!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Mailcatcher or something to listen to the port? You might need to start mailcatcher.

```
Starting MailCatcher
==> smtp://127.0.0.1:1025
```